# HTML elements with a state

Tags: html, tags, state, element

Are there more HTML elements witch have a state property like these:

`<details open>`, `<input type=checkbox checked>`, `<input type=radio checked>` ?

Comment: I mean <input /> has <input disabled required /> of my head

Answer (score 2):

## defer

```
<script src="index.js" defer></script>
```

## autoplay - controls  - loop - muted

```
<video controls autoplay loop muted></video>
<audio controls autoplay loop muted></audio>
```

## autofocus

```
<button autofocus></button>
```

## defualt

```
  <track src="subtitles.vtt" default>
```

## disabled - required

```
<input type="submit" disabled required>
```

these are ones that i had thought of there might be more [here's a list of all attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp)

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.